# Conditional formating with VBA on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, forms, conditional-formatting

I will try to be as specific as I can, but this is a quite complex thing.

At my work we have a specific system that we upload big excel data files with multiple sheets named A, B, C etc. sheet (it can vary how much we have based on the characteristics we need to look at) and it generates a result file based on the values that the original contained. It is about chemicals, and the columns contain characteristics of the chemical. At the result file there will be an additional column called "RESULTS" that the system inserts. The place of this column can vary, so it would be important to have a VBA that looks for a header name, and not just a specific column on each sheet. The header name is always the same. Some of these files can contain several tens of thousands of rows, and in the result column there will be codes and their definition. Like "11AA: acidity exceeds threshold". Usually there are several, 6-8 codes in those cells at once only separated with a space. The problem here is that there are codes that needs further investigation because it is too acid, or something, and there are ones that don`t need investigation.  In one cell there can be like 8 code, and there are cases with 70k+ rows and typically there are only a few with codes that I need to investigate. I have a complete list of codes that are problematic, I can`t use vlookup, because there are several codes and text in cells.
The goal would be to just paint those cells red in which we have these problematic codes on every sheet, so that I would only need to filter for colour and won`t need to search for every code one by one that the system generated.

In short: I have a files with several sheets, and the sheet`s number can vary. On those sheets I have a column called RESULTS and it changes from file to file, and sheet to sheet which column is the RESULTS. In that column I have codes and sentences, but it only the code matters. I would like the macro to look for certain codes in that column among the text from a list of codes I specified.

Comment: You should prove somehow that you investigated and tried creating something to solve your problem, on your own. Then, where from that "list of codes I specified" to be taken? Does "paint those cells red" mean to change the cells font in Red, or to make the cells interior Red? If I understand that those specific "codes" represent the whole content of a cell, not part of the cell, should my understanding be correct? And the last **important** issue to be clarified: Are all column headers on the same row, in all the sheets? If yes, is it the first row, or not?

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub HeighlightCells()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngH As Range, rngCol As Range, iRow As Long, arr, pList, mtch, i As Long
  Const hd As String = "RESULTS"
  
  iRow = 1 'the row of the column headers
  pList = Split("Code1,Code2,Code3,Code4,Code5", ",") 'the list of problematic codes. It can be extracted from a range, too
          'take care to keep only a comma between the codes enumeration! Not ", "...
  For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets  'iterate between all sheets
      Set rngH = sh.rows(iRow).Find(What:=hd, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) 'find the column keeping the header
      If Not rngH Is Nothing Then  'if it has been found:
            lastR = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, rngH.Column).End(xlUp).row 'last row on that column
            arr = sh.Range(rngH.Offset(1), sh.cells(lastR, rngH.Column)).value 'put the range in an array (to work faster)
            For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array elements
                mtch = Application.match(arr(i, 1), pList, 0) 'try finding a match in the problematic codes area
                If Not IsError(mtch) Then     'if the code has been found
                    If rngCol Is Nothing Then 'create the range first cell
                        Set rngCol = sh.cells(i - iRow + 2, rngH.Column)
                    Else
                        'make a Union between existing range and the new cell
                        Set rngCol = Union(rngCol, sh.cells(i - iRow + 2, rngH.Column))
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
      Else
        MsgBox "In sheet " & sh.Name & ", the header """ & hd & """ could not be found on the row " & iRow & "..."
      End If
      If Not rngCol Is Nothing Then rngCol.Interior.Color = vbRed: Set rngCol = Nothing
  Next sh
End Sub
```

Using Conditional Formatting will consume Excel resources and the formulae should often be adapted according to the new problematic/non problematic codes change.